# Did the Jedi Order use corporal punishment?

Tags: star-wars, jedi-training

I just read a fanfiction, where a Padawan is spanked for disobeying. Do you think this is realistic? Was corporal punishment allowed?

Comment: Master Yoda had something to say about causing suffering. The gist was that it was bad

Comment: *"Next time, try not to lose it. Remember, your weapon is your life"* *"Yes, Master"* *"And now for your spanking"* *"Yes, Master"*

Answer (score 12):

Based on the prequels, it seems extremely unlikely.  Corporal punishment gives individuals a motivation that is ultimately based on fear, and as Yoda says:  "Fear leads to anger.  Anger leads to hate.  Hate leads to suffering."  The Jedi council appears to take this philosophy very seriously, to harsh punishments for their students would seem to be a terrible idea.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure, but based on what I know, it’s unlikely that the Council would use corporal punishment. Padawans are meant to bond with their masters and a bond is built off of trust and compassion for one another. But a spanking would cause fear as a motivation and fear contradicts trust entirely. I dunno though. It also seems unlikely because in some situations, it could make a Padawan feel disliked or unfavored by their master. This could cause hatred for others, and we all know what comes after hatred. The Dark Side.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. This seems like complete speculation; can you cite any evidence that this is correct?